# How to reduce the promotional content web part images and boxes size in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image]I would like to reduce the size of boxes and images which I have on my promotional content.

Someone writing that it is possible by Jquery and by JS someone mentioning that it is possible by CSS just by adding script editor web part. But I can not get my answer,

How it can be doable from SharePoint Online and how can I change the size of that promotional content web part boxes that it is not affecting to other sites?

Comment: Please add a screenshot to can help you faster

Comment: In red place I have a picture and then a text. So I would like to decrease size of the all third boxes.

Comment: are you talking about Promoted Links?

Comment: Yes, I m talking about promoted links